# Random Effects Estimator in plm: system is computationally singular

Tags: r, panel-data, random-effects

Again, I'm getting an error that I don't know how to solve when attempting to create a random effects model of my panel data in plm. The code I use:

```
random<-plm(RenEnCon~WomenParl+GDPpercap+Pop+UrbanPop+FreedomHouse+RegimeType+HDI+WomenPolEmpowerIndex, data=pdata, model= "random", na.action=na.exclude)
```

results in this error:

```
Error in solve.default(crossprod(ZBeta)) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.63559e-21
```

Based on some research this may be because the data is unbalanced? If you have any idea what the issue is here or how to fix it it would be most appreciated.

Comment: This is related to your model's design matrix, I often hit it when I have a lot of groups and don't have multiple observations in each group? See this post on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76488/error-system-is-computationally-singular-when-running-a-glm)

Comment: Really helpful, thanks! This might be really basic but what do I actually do about it? I’m having trouble.

Comment: Remove some predictors and see if the error goes away

Comment: Thanks so much-- removing UrbanPop variable worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76488/error-system-is-computationally-singular-when-running-a-glm This helped my solve the problem. 
Once I removed UrbanPop variable the model worked, presumably because it removed homoscedasticity between urban population and overall population variables.